# Find SUM of Table columns between specific Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with several columns including a basic ascending number of 1-5 (Col A) & another with specific numeric data (Col B). I'm trying to create a query string to find the accumulated value of Col B fields between desired row numbers.

For example:

```
Column: A          Column: B

1                    5
2                    5
3                    5
4                    5
5                    5
```

I'm trying to return the combined value of Column B between Rows 2 & 4. which should result in 15.

Current Coding effort:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Column A BETWEEN >=2 & <=4");

{while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
$desirednumber=$row['Column B'];}
```

appreciate your help.

Comment: Please correct BETWEEN 2 AND 4 not BETWEEN >=2 & <=4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(ColumnB) as 'SumOfB' FROM $table WHERE ColumnA BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Comment: +1, but would be better to add a column alias so that the OP knows how to call it.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Sure, will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(columnB) as ColumnB FROM $table WHERE ColumnA BETWEEN 2 AND 4");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
{
   $desirednumber=$row['ColumnB'];
}
```